# How to add program executable with long path containing spaces and parameter using CMD and reg.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

It is necesary to add program executable with long path containing spaces and parameter to system startup with using of CMD and reg.exe.
It can be done this way:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "My Program" /t reg_sz /d "%ProgramFiles%\My Program\My Program.exe -parameter" /f
```

But it will not work beacause of the long path with spaces need adding extra symbols "\" to string to work correctly.
So how to add program executable with long path containing spaces and parameter using CMD and reg.exe?

Comment: What error message(s) did you get when you ran that command?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  [Edit] your post to include a statement of exactly what you expect to happen, and what actually happened.  It appears that the command works fine, but what is missing are the quotes in the registry value.

Comment: You probably need to replace `"%ProgramFiles%\My Program\My Program.exe -parameter"` by `"\"%ProgramFiles%\My Program\My Program.exe\" -parameter"`...

Comment: reg.exe probably parses its command line per MSVC rules and thus uses backslash to escape double quotes. This can get complicated if there are any of CMD's special characters in the path (in particular `&%()` are common -- `%` especially if you're looking to set a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value) because backslash is not an escape character in CMD. To CMD, the example string from @aschipfi looks like the following three segments: ["\", %ProgramFiles%\My Program\My Program.exe\ , " -parameter"]. The middle segment isn't quoted, so special characters in it need to be escaped with `^`.